# Browser Detection

Tags: c#, silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0

How can i detected the browser type in my silverlight application?

for example i want to know if my silverlight application is running on IE or Firefox Or GoogleChrome...

i'm using silverlight 4
and my programming language is c#

Comment: what do you need this info for? The whole point of plugins like silverlight and flash, is to develop apps that work in all browsers the same, because they only depend on the plugin and not on the browser

Comment: @Jens:  The "whole point" of HTML is that you shouldn't have to worry about what browser is rendering it and yet the gritty reality is that we do.   Silverlight can interact with the host page, what is available may vary from browser to browser.  For example "Data not saved, are you sure you want to close" is something that you need assistance from the browser to deliver.  How this is done may vary so in order to support multiple browsers some detection of the host browser may be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `HtmlPage.BrowserInformation` property.

Code Example (given a `TextBlock` called "txtOut"):-

```
    txtOut.Text = String.Format("Name: {0}\nVersion: {1}\nProduct Name: {2}\nProduct Version: {3}\nUser Agent: {4}\nPlatform: {5}",
        HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.Name,
        HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.BrowserVersion,
        HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.ProductName,
        HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.ProductVersion,
        HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.UserAgent,
        HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.Platform);
```

I have IE 7 and Firefox 3.6.6 and it would seem that `ProductName` and possible `ProductVersion` would be you best choice to determine the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, then u can use the [Browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) plugin of Jquery.

if you are using JS but not JQuery, then can follow this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) from w3schools

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, then you can use  **navigator.appName** for getting name of the browser.